# Quickly updating table from large tsv, retaining a timestamp

Tags: mysql, import

Consider this `tsv` file with millions of rows, where `uid` is a unique identifier of any possible value.

```
  1  audi    a3      blue
 42  ferrari f60     red
 23  porsche 911     green
```

It should be used to initially create a MySQL table, and then update it periodically:

```
imported | uid | type   | model | color
---------+-----+--------+-------+------
monday       1   audi     a3      blue
monday      42   ferrari  f40     red
monday      23   porsche  911     green
```

Now, observe the following requirements:

1. If `uid` exists, the row should be updated, *except* `imported`, which should be retained.
2. If `uid` doesn't exist, new values should be inserted, and `imported` set to current timestamp.

Thus, the table might look like this later:

```
imported | uid | type   | model | color
---------+-----+--------+-------+-------
monday       1   audi     a3      blue
monday      42   ferrari  f60     white
monday      23   porsche  911     purple
thursday     6   bugatti  veyron  yellow
```

In other words, the procedure should update the table, but keep a distinction of when a row was imported for the first time. Doing this programatically is easy, but will be slow.

So how can I do this using only `mysqlimport`, `load data infile` or a similar very fast method? Using `--delete` and `--ignore` do not seem to offer a way to achieve the desired effect.

Answer (score 2):

It's 4 statements:

```
CREATE TABLE Staging ...;  (and a DROP or TRUNCATE)
LOAD DATA ... INTO Staging ...;
INSERT INTO Real (...)  SELECT ... FROM Staging LEFT JOIN Real ...;
UPDATE Real JOIN Staging ON ... SET ...;
```

The `LOAD` is very fast for getting the TSV/CSV into a table.  `staging` is purely for this periodic 'update' process.

The `SELECT` finds the 'new' rows and feeds them to the `INSERT` to do the rest add new rows.

The `UPDATE` is to update all the rows for which you have new data, and to update `imported`.

If `uid` is `AUTO_INCREMENT`, I deliberately avoided `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...` because the latter would 'burn' ids, thereby threatening to eventually overflow the range of `uid`.

For more discussion, see [*my blog on ingestion*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/data-warehousing-high-speed-ingestion/#normalization) .  That section of the blog details how to augment a Normalization table with one `INSERT` and one `UPDATE`.  Your case is very similar.  The rest of the blog focuses on 'continual' ingestion, unlike your 'periodic' ingestion.

If your incremental load is bigger than a million rows, there are other aspects we need to discuss.

Comment: I get the approach, and had something similar in mind. Unless someone has a more automatic method, I guess this will be the accepted answer.